# URL Connect to XAMPP Server using Android Emulator

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

I am writing a program in which i am *trying to store data into XAMPP Server via Android Emulator*, but i am getting error while inserting data into XAMPP.

Error: Unknown Status!

and i dam sure that i am getting this error because i am not using correct url to connect

Please check my below url to connect to XAMPP Server via Android Emulator:

```
   String url = "http://ipaddress/test.php"
```

I have tried this by using my IP address also, but whenever i browse it on browser getting  **Object Not Found**:

*The requested URL '/test.php' was not found on the RomPager server*

```
  String url = "http://127.0.0.1/test.php"

  String url = "http://10.0.2.2/test.php"
```

**Note :** *I have tested my php code before and it works fine, so something wrong in my URL*

I am using below lines in PHP Script:

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannnot Connect to Database");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("registration");
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your emulator, not your computer.

Comment: Use 10.0.2.2 as IP address instead. This is the IP alias inside the emulator for the loopback adapter 127.0.0.1 of your development machine.

Comment: Try http://10.0.2.2/test.php from PC browser, if that really works. It has to work both from PC and emulator. Otherwise, you have to modify server configuration.

Comment: @Pihhan yes i agree with you buddy, i have tested using browser it worked but via emulator it is not working, how to modify server configuration, is it in config.inc need guidance

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 its means localhost

**insted of that Use your PC(Personal Computer)'s IP Address.**

like:

if my pc's ip is: 192.168.0.1 then URL is

```
String url = "http://192.168.0.1/test.php"
```

Comment: yes i have tried with my pc's ip address, but getting Object Not Found, i have updated placed complete detail of page please check above

Comment: have you open your url in browser?? http://10.0.2.2/test.php open this in browser.. tell me what happend..

Comment: able to store data into xampp server @DhavalSodhaParmar

Comment: check this tutorial: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/connecting-mysql-database-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link to localhost (127.0.0.1), as emulator has its own network address and its own, separate localhost. So

```
    http://127.0.0.1/
```

connects to emulator itself. Unless you have android web server running, you will get connection refused error.

You can use ADB from Android SDK to forward ports from local PC to android device. But I think you cannot forward port from android device to PC.
See adb forward help, but I believe it is another direction.

Easiest way to get it working is to use name of your computer instead localhost. You have to use real IP accessible from network, you can find that using ipconfig. Depending on your network configuration, you may be able to use full hostname with domain. Ie. mycomputer.example.org. Just append DNS suffix from ipconfig and try.

You may have to reconfigure your apache to listen also on external address and use firewall to block access from outside. If you use virtual host for 127.0.0.1 on apache server, you have also move it to virtual host with another address.

And it seems %SYSTEM%/drivers/etc/hosts file will not work, it has to be name nslookup can resolve. Easier is to use local IP, if that is not changing often. In other case, use dyndns :)

Answer (score 0):

View this
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

use this "10.0.2.2" ip address it is equal to localhost in your hosting device

Answer (score 0):

Xampp was working with Port: **80** as shown in below image. So writing below ip address as `http://10.0.2.2:80/` worked for me. Hope this helps someone.

[image: Xampp]

Answer (score -1):

Add to `build.gradle`:

```
Android{
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```